# How to fix 'Heap has been corrupted 'error in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, heap-corruption

When I run the program, I get exception "heap has been corrupted" after completion of the function

I have read that this exception may cause if you are using memory that has been freed, or when you are writing to index which is out of array index. But none of the cases applies here. I have read other answers of some problems but it didn't help much.

```
`char fileNametoExport[26]="d:\\FOlder1\\part1.ipt";
 char WorkingFolderName[260] ="d:\\folder";
 int start = rFind(fileNametoExport, '\\');
 int finish = rFind(fileNametoExport, '.');
 if (start == -1)
 start = 0;
char partname[260];
strcpy(partname,substr(fileNametoExport, start, finish));
::AfxMessageBox((LPCTSTR)partname);
char xtfile[260];
char xmltxtfile[260];
strcpy(xtfile, strcat(WorkingFolderName, partname));
strcat(xtfile, "__Default.x_t");
strcpy(xmltxtfile, WorkingFolderName);
strcat(xmltxtfile,"_XT_SE_INV_Default_SOLID_0_Solid1_xt.xmt_txt");`
```

function rfind() to find occurence of char in char array-

```
int rFind(char* s, char c)
    {
    int sz = 0;
    char *tmp = s;
    while (*tmp != '\0')
    {
        sz++;
        tmp++;
    }
    for (int i = sz - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (*(s + i) == c)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

function substr() to get substring from position x to y (y exclusive)

```
char* substr(char* s, const int b, const int f)
{
    char *str = new char[f - b];
    int t = 0;
    for (int i = b; i != f; i++)
    {
        str[t] = s[i];
        t++;
    }
    str[t] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

P.S- While giving input I ensure that fileNametoExport always contains '.' and '\'.

Comment: So what makes you think the code above is the cause of the error?

Comment: Incidentally, your code is bugged, you should have char `fileNametoExport[26]="d:\\FOlder1\\part1.ipt";` and `char WorkingFolderName[260] ="d:\\folder";`. Backslashes must be escaped in string literals.

Comment: ::AfxMessageBox((LPCTSTR)partname);     ~~does this message box show valid values?

Comment: @dorKKnight , no it doesn't show valid values.

Comment: @john, I am accepting values from stdin. I added these 2 lines for better understanding purpose. Thanks for letting me know the bugs in those lines.

Comment: @john adding this code caused the problem, so I am sure that problem is in this code

Comment: @SonaliDBhavsar Unfortunately it's not that easy. Bugs in one part of your code may only appear when changes are made in another part of your code. That's the nature of C++. And as you say, there is no heap corruption in those lines of code, so it seems very likely that your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: @SonaliDBhavsar Incidentally, the best way to protect yourself against heap corruption problems is to use C++ features such as `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of C strings and arrays. The code above is pure C.

Comment: can you please check if   ` int start = rFind(fileNametoExport, '\\'); `  
the variable start has a valid value. 'rfind' is function with std::string, might not work with char array .

Comment: Yes start has valid value which is in range of 0 to length of filenameToExport-1

Comment: What are the `rfind` and `substr` functions? please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your program do not check lengths of input strings. You can receive a string longer than your buffer and program will fail.
2. If your program get `fileNametoExport = "d:\\somefolder\\somefilewithoutdot"` ,  `finish` will be -1 and program fail at `strcpy(partname,substr(fileNametoExport, start, finish));` .
3. Program writes after buffer in `char* substr(char* s, const int b, const int f)` at line

   ```
   str[t] = '\0';
   ```

   because `t` at this point equal `f-b` , size of `str` buffer.

Function `_ASSERTE( _CrtCheckMemory( ) );` from `<crtdbg.h>` very useful when searching for bugs like this. Put it around suspicious code and it fails after your bug. It works only in debug.